# Running dynamically loaded jQuery after dynamically loaded content has finished loading

Tags: jquery, svg, svgpanzoom

I'm dynamically sending an `html` snippet to the browsers. This snippet contains an `SVG` and a piece of Javascript:

```
<div class="traffic-map-wrap">
    <embed id="traffic-map" type="image/svg+xml" class="traffic-map" src="{traffic-map-svg}" />
</div>

<script>
  $(function() {
    svgPanZoom('#traffic-map', {
      zoomEnabled: true,
      controlIconsEnabled: false,
      minZoom: 0.1,
      maxZoom: 10000
    });
  });
</script>
```

The function in the snippet runs fine, but the `svgPanZoom` fails because it is being run before the `SVG` is fully loaded (`TypeError: e.getSVGDocument(...) is null`). On the other hand if I introduce an `alert()` and give it a couple of seconds before clicking, it all works fine:

```
<script>
  $(function() {
    alert();
    svgPanZoom('#traffic-map', {
      zoomEnabled: true,
      controlIconsEnabled: false,
      minZoom: 0.1,
      maxZoom: 10000
    });
  });
</script>
```

Obviously this is not a glorious solution so **how can I run a dynamically loaded script after everything has been loaded**? Some equivalent of `$(window).load(function(){...});`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try checking recursively if SVG was loaded...

```
$(function() {
    svgPanZoom_launcher();
});

function svgPanZoom_launcher() {
    var svg = document.getElementById("traffic-map").getSVGDocument();
    if (svg == null) {
        setTimeout("svgPanZoom_launcher()", 400);
    } else {
        svgPanZoom('#traffic-map', {
            zoomEnabled: true,
            controlIconsEnabled: false,
            minZoom: 0.1,
            maxZoom: 10000
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't `checkReady()` be `svgPanZoom_launcher()`? It works like a charm though. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, my bad! :) np!

Comment: Or you could listen for embed load event. Like in this example http://ariutta.github.io/svg-pan-zoom/demo/dynamic-load.html